# Concatenate Files In Order Linux Command

Tags: linux, sorting, cat, fastq

I just started learning to use command line. Hopefully this is not a dump question.

I have the following files in my directory:

```
L001_R1_001.fastq 
L002_R2_001.fastq 
L004_R1_001.fastq 
L005_R2_001.fastq
L001_R2_001.fastq 
L003_R1_001.fastq 
L004_R2_001.fastq 
L006_R1_001.fastq
L002_R1_001.fastq 
L003_R2_001.fastq 
L005_R1_001.fastq 
L006_R2_001.fastq
```

You can see in the filenames, it's a mix of R1 and R2 and the numbers after L00 are not sorted.

I want to concatenate files in the order of filename, separately for R1 and R2 files.

If I do it manually, it will look like the following:

```
# for R1 files
cat L001_R1_001.fastq L002_R1_001.fastq L003_R1_001.fastq L004_R1_001.fastq L005_R1_001.fastq L006_R1_001.fastq > R1.fastq


# for R2 files
cat L001_R2_001.fastq L002_R2_001.fastq L003_R2_001.fastq L004_R2_001.fastq L005_R2_001.fastq L006_R2_001.fastq > R2.fastq
```

Could you please help me write a script that I can re-use later?
Thank you!

Comment: Hm, does your shell's `glob` order? 'cause you could use `cat *_R1_*.fastq > R1.fastq` then...

Answer (score 4):

```
cat `ls -- *_R1_*.fastq | sort` >R1.fastq
cat `ls -- *_R2_*.fastq | sort` >R2.fastq
```

The `| sort` is not needed on most systems because `ls` sorts the files by name.

If the names of the files contain whitespace, then do this first:

```
IFS='
'
```

Comment: I believe use of `ls` and `sort` is redundant

Comment: sort would sort _lines_ of input. consider using _ls -1_ instead. moreover, it might be a good idea to perform version sort: _sort -V_

Comment: *-1* for ls is redundant, ls writes one filename per line when writing to a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Try using wildcard character `*`. It will automatically expand file names in alphabetical order.

```
cat L*_R1_001.fastq > R1.fastq
cat L*_R2_001.fastq > R2.fastq
```

**EDIT**:

If above command doesn't give desired sorting, try overriding locale setting using `LC_ALL=C` as sugested by [Fredrik Pihl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297323/fredrik-pihl)

```
LC_ALL=C cat L*_R1_001.fastq > R1.fastq
```

Comment: Perhaps hint at using `LC_ALL=C cat L*_R1_001.fastq > R1.fastq` so no funny things happens due to different locale

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks for your feedback. I have added your suggestion in ans.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `*` sorts the filenames. Use `ls` for that.

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl: `LC_ALL=C` has no effect on the sorting and matching in `*` because the shell expands `*` earlier than applying the environment variable change.